# Can't install ESLint in project folder - npm error code ENOSELF

Tags: npm, terminal, npm-install, eslint, eslintrc

I'm struggling to install ESLint from my terminal (locally in my project folder).
I'm running this command:
`sudo npm install eslint --save-dev`
However, an npm error with code ENOSELF is returned, with the following message

```
npm ERR! code ENOSELF
npm ERR! Refusing to install package with name "eslint" under a package
npm ERR! also called "eslint". Did you name your project the same
npm ERR! as the dependency you're installing?
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! For more information, see:
npm ERR!     <https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install#limitations-of-npms-install-algorithm>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/[username]/.npm/_logs/2020-01-07T14_32_27_111Z-debug.log
```

I have no folder nor files named eslint or anything remotely close to that. In my project directory I have a collection of html, js and csv files that have been edited with VSCode.

I'm really confused why this error is happening, and would appreciate help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the `name` property in your `package.json` is not `eslint`

Comment: I didn't have a json file so created one and it seems to have helped somewhat... Now when I try and run eslint [filename] I get the error -bash: /usr/local/bin/eslint: No such file or directory

Comment: Because eslint is installed in the `node_modules`. You can run it either with `npx eslint` or `./node_modules/.bin/eslint` or install eslint globally `npm install eslint -g` to run it from any directory

Comment: Thanks, that's sorted it - sorry for being a bit slow, I'm pretty new to nodeJS!